# Limits And Asymptotes Question

Tags: limits

If $f$ has an asymptote as $x \to \infty$, then $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}$ exists,
is true.

If $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}$ exists, then $f$ has an asymptote as $x\to\infty$,
is false.

Asymptote means that there exists some $m$ and $b$ as $x\to\infty$, $[f(x) − (mx + b)] = 0$.
Why is claim 1 true and claim 2 false?

Comment: Please consider improving the presentation of your question. For claim 2, consider $f(x)=\ln(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

If $ f $ has the line $ y=mx+n $ as an asymptote at $ +\infty $, then

$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}(f(x)-(mx+b))=0$$

and
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{f(x)-(mx+b))}{x}=0$$

which gives

$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}(\frac{f(x)}{x}-m)=0$$
or
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}=m$$

But,
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=0$$
and
$x\mapsto \sin(x) $ has NO asymptote at $ +\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_\infty f(x)/x$ only means the tangent line at a point takes a given direction as the point goes to $\infty$, whereas the existence of an asymptote adds that the curve gets closer and closer to a line  with this direction.

For instance, if $\lim_\infty\frac{f(x)}x=0$, the tangent line to the curve gets more and more horizontal. This is the case for, say $f(x)=\sqrt x$. If the curve has a horizontal asymptote, the function has a finite limit at $\infty.

I'll some words about the terminology: if $\lim_\infty\frac{f(x)}x=m$, but there's no asymptote, one says that the representative curve has a *parabolic branch in the direction with slope* $m$.